# How to generate DNS Query from a specific port?

Tags: python, networking, dns, network-programming

I am trying to generate dns traffic, which I am able to with curl or ping as well as this library : http://www.dnspython.org/ Basically I am generating a random URL and querying for that

But the issue is dns queries are generated from a random port, Is there a way to generate DNS query from a specific port (which i can provide?)

P.S. I am not bothered about the response to the query at the moment ( and am aware that it is received on the port 53).

Thanks

Comment: Why? DNS will respond to whatever port you use. NB The *request* goes to port 53. The response goes to the local port of the requesting socket.

Comment: Yes, but that 'whatever' port, can we specify that anyhow? I need to keep track of which query goes through which port. @user207421

Comment: Well if the toolkit supports binding the client socket explicitly, or specifying the client port, yes, otherwise no, but the answer is in the documentation you cited, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation at http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.16.0/dns.resolver.Resolver-class.html

```
query(self, qname, rdtype=1, rdclass=1, tcp=False, source=None, raise_on_no_answer=True, source_port=0, lifetime=None)

[...]

*source_port*, an ``int``, the port from which to send the message.
```